# New ReCaptcha (invisible) not working

Tags: recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am trying to implement the new invisible reCaptcha, but it is not working.

First, event tough I have created a new key with the "invisible" option, changed the key in my application, when I look in my console I can see this request:

> https://www.google.com/recaptcha/**api2**/anchor?k=.....

I think this is not the correct api, right?

My code for the importing part is like this:

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>`

Which is right according to the doc...

Second, I chose to put the captcha in a div (which is ok according to the doc):

`<div id="captchaSignup" 
    class="g-recaptcha"
    data-size="invisible" data-badge="inline"></div>`

I am also using the render function to declare the callback and the site-key:

`grecaptcha.render(document.getElementById('captchaSignup'), {
                    'sitekey' : '...',
                    'callback' : function(response) {$rs.validCaptcha=response;$s.$apply()}
                  });`

This works as a captcha solution, but not as the invisible one since it is still showing the box. I know that I also have to use the execute function, but since I am still seeing the box, I think I am not in that phase yet.. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case of "invisible" recaptcha, `grecaptcha.render()` api takes optional third boolean parameter called `inherit` and defaults to `false`. If its value is specified as `true`, only then recaptcha uses existing data-* attributes on `.g-recaptcha` element for parameters not specified in options to `render()`, otherwise it treats as if the parameter is missing.

Since you are not passing this parameter with `true` value, it never reads `data-size="invisible"` value that you have on your HTML element and thereby goes on to render it as visible recaptcha.

Try this:

```
grecaptcha.render(document.getElementById('captchaSignup'), {
                    'sitekey' : '...',
                    'callback' : function(response) { ... }
                  }, true);       // <-- this is the change. Pass "true" here
```